# Show file name in `frame-title-format` in `vertico-posframe`

Tags: frame-title-format

I have `(setq frame-title-format "%b")` in my Emacs config. And it works properly. But I also use the `vertico-posframe` package. Every time I go into the `vertico-posframe` frame the frame title becomes empty.

Because I use commands (which displayed by `vertico-posframe`) quite often, the frame title constantly switching between displaying and hiding is a bit annoying. I'd like entering `vertico-posframe` will not clear the frame title (i.e. display the "%b" of the parent frame). How can I do that? Thanks.

Normal situation

[image]

In `vertico-posframe` the frame title is cleared

[image]

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, I would suggest opening an issue in https://github.com/minad/vertico or https://github.com/tumashu/vertico-posframe

Comment: I think it is not an "issue" of either package, just a customize thing.

Comment: Then the expert(s) at that site should be able to point you to the option that you have to customize (they know their code better).